# Discord.js v14 command giving multiple errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

EDIT :- turns out the previous error was due to my command handler itself! Now that I figured it out there's this one heck of a big error .... I mean multiple errors. Umm so I really need help.
(PS :- Sorry for the trouble!)

This Code is giving me a lot of error:-

```
const { Discord, Client, Partials, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
  GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages] })
  const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'av',
  aliases: ['av'],
  category: 'Util',
  utilisation: '{prefix}av <mention user or dont>',
    async run(client,message,args) {
      console.log("test")
       let member = message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.member;
       let avatar = member.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 1024, dynamic: true });
       const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle(`${member}'s Avatar`)
        .setImage(avatar)
        .setColor("BLACK")
        .setAuthor(member);
      message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
    },
};
```

This is the BIG error.

```
{
  name: 'av',
  aliases: [ 'av' ],
  category: 'Util',
  utilisation: '{prefix}av <mention user or dont>',
  run: [AsyncFunction: run]
}
av
C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1252
    return errors.length === 0 ? Result.ok(finalObject) : Result.err(new CombinedPropertyError(errors));
   ^
CombinedPropertyError: Received one or more errors
    at ObjectValidator.handleIgnoreStrategy (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1252:70)
    at ObjectValidator.handleStrategy (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1105:47)
    at ObjectValidator.handle (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1205:17)
    at ObjectValidator.parse (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:201:88)
    at EmbedBuilder.setAuthor (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:223:26)
    at Object.run (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\commands\av.js:19:10)       
    at module.exports (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\events\messageCreate.js:14:18)
    at Client.emit (node:events:524:35)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:28:14)
    at module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32) {
  errors: [
    [
      'name',
      MissingPropertyError: A required property is missing        
          at ObjectValidator.handleIgnoreStrategy (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1227:27)      
          at ObjectValidator.handleStrategy (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1105:47)
          at ObjectValidator.handle (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1205:17)
          at ObjectValidator.parse (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:201:88)
          at EmbedBuilder.setAuthor (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:223:26)
          at Object.run (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\commands\av.js:19:10) 
          at module.exports (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\events\messageCreate.js:14:18)
          at Client.emit (node:events:524:35)
          at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:28:14)      
          at module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\WebDev\Sutilbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32) {
        property: 'name'
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I am not able to understand the error.
Even if you can explain the error that's enough.

Please help me!!

Comment: Why do you have two `client` in your second example? How and where do you call the `run` method? What intents have you enabled?

Comment: ```async run(client,message){  ```  is in line 10 in second code

Comment: ```GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates
  ],
  partials: [
    Partials.Channel,
    Partials.Message,
    Partials.User,
    Partials.GuildMember,
    Partials.Reaction
  ]
``` these are the intents.

Comment: Intents seem to be fine, but that's not how you call the `run` method. And notice what parameters you use, in one file it's `run(client,message)` in the other one it's `run(message, args)`. That's not possible.

Comment: tried but doesnt work

Comment: What do you mean _"tried"_?

Comment: tried to add the client parameter to the run but it didnt work

Comment: If the second command works, then the correct order for the parameters are `(client, message)` which is probably why the first command failed since the parameters there are different

Comment: @Caladan i tried changing the parameters but it didnt work

Comment: @MinecraftGeek Can you update the code then so we can see?

Comment: Hi, I updated my question

Sorry for the touble!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you call `run` correctly, but regarding  the errors you stated, it is on line 19 of commands/av.js the `setAuthor` method.

## Problem

You used the `setAuthor` method incorrectly. You should include `name` property in `setAuthor`

## Solution

Don't do the following as `member` is not string.

```js
.setAuthor({ name: member })
```

Change it with

```js
.setAuthor({ name: 'member name'})
```

If you want to have the icon, simply add the `iconURL` property after the `name` property.

You should only pass the string to the `name` property.

## References

[String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

[Discord.js Documentation (Embed Author)](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/EmbedAuthorData)

Comment: so like .setAuthor({ name: member})?

Comment: tried but didnt work still got error https://srcshare.io/63ff40813b268c90ce0cbb1c

Comment: @MinecraftGeek You should passing string to the `name` property. For instance, 'ExampleMember' is a string, you are passing the guild member where it cannot be handled. Make sure you only have `string` on the name property. I have updated the answer to make it more clear.